# How to convert OmniGraffle files to a non-proprietary format

Tags: conversion, microsoft-visio, svg, graphviz, omnigraffle

I have inherited a bunch of graphs in OmniGraffle format which I need to edit. I do not have access to a Mac, and I have no desire to buy OmniGraffle either. I've looked at the `.graffle` files which are just zipped XML files, so I guess I could "just" convert them to SVG or Graphviz format myself ... but I hope someone already did the work for me ;)

Are there any free (as in beer and/or speech) tools out there that can convert `.graffle` files to a non-proprietary format, preferably Graphviz? Whether the tools is for Windows or Linux doesn't matter.

Failing that, an OmniGraffle → Visio converter?

Comment: I'm curious why my question is considered "not constructive" ... it fits the FAQ definition of "What kind of questions can I ask here?" and is a "practical, answerable question based on an actual problem that I face".